# What is the meaning of "epic" as an adjective??

Tags: adjectives

Lately, I saw this used many times especially in social media and some people have a caption for there photo with it, so l just want to know its exact meaning as an adjective "that's epic or that was epic"  as search alot for its meaning in Merriam Webster and others but what l found the meaning of the noun but l did not find the adjective meaning.

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/epic

Comment: Which version of "Merriam Webster" did you look in? The online version has an entry for *epic* as an adjective and includes a nice usage note for its contemporary, colloquial  usage. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epic

Comment: I used to use the application for Merriam Webster

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/epic

5) Slang. spectacular; very impressive; awesome:
Their burgers and fries are epic!

The noun refers to "Epic Poems". These poems are large, heroic and grandiose. As an extension, anything being compared to them is also large, heroic and grandiose.

"Epic fail" would be the ironic use of "Heroic".